# Do I need JPanel always?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

I am now writing code simple GUI that's for start the game window. I only need Do you want to start game message and start button on the window. But I have a confusing concepts for the `JFrame` and `JPanel`. Actually, I thought I need to add `JPanel` to `JFrame` to add the other components such as `JLabel`, `JButton`,...etc. But I realized I don't actually need `JPanel`. I can just add the components simply use `add(button)`, `add(label)` to `JFrame`. So why I need `JPanel`. And I think `JFrame` doesn't need `JPanel` but `JPanel` need `JFrame`. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)... You will want to have panels instead of a single frame for all the gui elements.

Comment: When you add components in JFrame, those get added into the JFrame's content pane. You can use jFrame.getContentPane().add(button), and it will behave same as adding components to JFrame directly.

Comment: JFrame's content pane is a Container class. Only you need to have a container to add components. JPanel is a container. Some other containers are like - JLayeredPane etc.

Comment: Preferably, you'd start with a `JPanel`, why? Because it's easier to switch between multiple panels.  The frame then just acts as the "top level container" around which you do everything else

Answer (score 1):

No, not always. A simple graphical user interface may be implemented by just adding components "directly" to a JFrame. But in order to get more flexibility, you would always use JPanels. For example, to employ different layouts in different parts of the GUI, to group certain components together, etc.

A JFrame is backed by a [`JRootPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html), a part of which is a `contentPane`.

[image]

(image from [Oracle Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/doc-files/JRootPane-2.gif))

When you add components to a JFrame, you are really adding them to the content pane, e.g.: `frame.getContentPane().add(Component)`.

A JFrame is a common starting scene of a Swing GUI application, while a JPanel is intended to be put in another scene (container). Since both content pane and a JPanel inherit from the same class ([Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html)) you may use them in a similar manner, as far as adding components to them goes.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need `JPanel` always?

No. Well, unless you need a Swing GUI. Then yes.

Another answer replied words to the effect. *"No, you can add components direct to a frame"* What they *missed* was that components added to a `JFrame` are added to the content pane (automatically). The content pane **is a** `JPanel`.

Having said that:

1. I (and many others) would recommend designing an app based around a main content panel, then adding that panel to a top-level container as needed. The top level container might be a `JFrame`, `JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JOptionPane` ..
2. What prompted the question? A `JPanel` is a very 'light weight' container (in more ways than one). A GUI can contain 1000s and not be burdened by doing so. Of course, that's a rare requirement, but just saying .. use panels as needed and don't worry about it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!!